# Is $Ax$ a matrix or a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $m$ and $n$ be distinct positive integers with $n > 1$. Suppose $A\in{\mathbb{M}_{m×n}(\mathbb{F})}$ and that $x\in{\mathbb{F}^n}$. Is $Ax$ a matrix or a vector?

As I see it:

> $Ax$ is a product of a matrix and a vector of compatible size, and this product results in a vector, hence, $Ax$ is a vector.

Is it true?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Matrices also form a vector space under addition and scalar multiplication, so also matrices are vectors in this sense.  More precisely, $M_{m,n}(F)$ is a vector space over $F$. On the other hand, every vector in $F^n$ can be considered as a $n\times 1$-matrix. Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45366/are-all-vectors-matrices).

Comment: An entirely correct, but useless, answer is "Yes".  An equally correct answer is "No."  It all comes down to what you mean by a "vector" and a "matrix".

Answer (score 0):

All matrices are vectors so it is trivially true. $Ax \in \mathbb{F}^n$ is also true as you have deduced.

Comment: Do you mean to say, rather, that all vectors are matrices?

Comment: Vectors are matrices and matrices are vectors.  The space of all $m\times n$ matrices is a vector space.  Additionally, a vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$ can be used as a $1\times n$ or a $n\times 1$ matrix, depending on context.  For example, the dot product of vectors $\vec a\cdot \vec b=\overleftrightarrow a^T\overleftrightarrow b$

Comment: This answer is not helpful. You are mixing up two different notions of vectors, one meaning $\mathbb F^n$ and the other one meaning "member of abstract vector space".

Comment: @shuhalo No, I'm only using "member of an abstract vector space" which happens to include matrices and $\mathbb{F}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I set $\mathbb{F}=:F$ and $\displaystyle{\mathbb{M}_{m×n}(\mathbb{F})=:F^{m\times n}}$.

The other answer says that $\displaystyle{F}^n=F^{1\times n}=F^{n\times 1}$ such that $Ax$ is both a vector and a matrix. That's okay as long as we don't take the equality too literally. In my opinion, it would be better to write
$$\displaystyle{F}^n\cong F^{1\times n}\cong F^{n\times 1}$$

As dicussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4207588/572841), we can characterize $\displaystyle{F}^n$ by a universal property, which defines $\displaystyle{F}^n$ up to a natural isomorphism. It is immediate to see that the set $\displaystyle{F^{n\times 1}}$ together with the projections $$\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_n\colon F^{n\times 1}\to F$$
defined by
$$\pi_i(A)=A_{i1}\in F$$
has the universal property of $\displaystyle{F}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use an $m\times n$-Matrix $A\in{\mathbb{M}_{m×n}(\mathbb{F})}$ to represent a linear function from the vector space ${\mathbb{F}^n}$ to the vectros space ${\mathbb{F}^n}$. So $x\in{\mathbb{F}^n}$ is a vector and $Ax \in{\mathbb{F}^m}$ is a vector. But of course vectors can be views as $1\times n$ matrices or $m\times 1$ matrices, too.